# Dont get row from db by model, but get it by facade DB

Tags: php, database, laravel, orm, model

I don't know why, but mt User model dot gets row from DB. But facade DB get it. At model also nothing special. I create this DB row by the factory before I get it from DB.
  What it can be?

```
User::where('public_key', $data['merchant_key'])->where('type', 'merchant')->first()

DB::table('users')->where('public_key', $data['merchant_key'])->where('type', 'merchant')->first()
```

Comment: can you share your user model?

Comment: What response do you get when you do it by model? An exception or just an empty result?

Comment: @SeverinDK  It's return NULL

Comment: Can you share your user model?

Comment: @zahidhasanemon https://docs.google.com/document/d/1DVzpTKCmigMnbBP7YFoqyVqiHOSGrFJZNZlbvXPxquI/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Don't share external link. Just paste it in your question.

Comment: @zahidhasanemon but this model really big to paste at question...

Comment: Just leave out all getters and things like that. Just show us the basic setup of the model. Strip out anything that's not important for this issue.

Comment: Share the basic setup of the model. Are you using `softdelete`?

Comment: @zahidhasanemon  I deleted Softdeete trait from model and now its work. Do you know for what it? I think just deleteng trait is not an issue..

Answer (score 0):

You have used Softdelete in your model which looks for a `deleted_at` column in your table. If not found it will throw an error. So if you use softdelete trait make sure your table has a `deleted_at` column.

And for your information, softdeleted rows will not appear if you are getting data using model. But if you are getting data using DB facade, softdeleted rows will appear too. 
Read about softdelete in [Laravel Documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent#soft-deleting)

Answer (score 0):

it's because ,may be you are using **softdelete**.model will add additional query(scope) that(where deleted_at is null).
and **Db facade will not check for it** as softdelete trait is used inside model.